# How do I get all checkbox value base on different names?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$('input[name^=tc]').click(function(){
            var attr = $(this).attr('name');
            $(this).siblings('input[name='+attr+']').prop('checked', false);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
1
<input  name="tc0" value="Y" type="checkbox">
<input name="tc0"  value="N"type="checkbox">
2
<input name="tc1" value="Y" type="checkbox">
<input name="tc1" value="N" type="checkbox">
3
<input name="tc2" value="Y" type="checkbox">
<input name="tc2" value="N" type="checkbox">
```

How can I get the final value of all checkbox base on their name?
For example, if I check value "Y" for tc0, value "N" for tc1, value "Y" for tc2.

How can I get "YNN" or ["Y", "N" ,"N"] back to me?

Comment: When/How do you want that to happen? ... And why do you use a script to make a checkbox input act as a radio input, why not use radio input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, I going to assume there was a reason why you aren't using RADIO instead of CHECKBOX, since RADIO accomplishes the single check per group without the extra Jquery on click.

```js
//changed CLICK to CHANGE

$('input[name^=tc]').change(function(){
var attr = $(this).attr('name');
$(this).siblings('input[name='+attr+']').prop('checked', false);
});

//get ids

vals = "";
$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(){
vals += $(this).val();
});
console.log(vals);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input checked name="tc0" value="Y" type="checkbox">
<input name="tc0"  value="N"type="checkbox">
<input checked name="tc1" value="Y" type="checkbox">
<input name="tc1" value="N" type="checkbox">
<input checked name="tc2" value="Y" type="checkbox">
<input name="tc2" value="N" type="checkbox">
```

Answer (score 1):

The logic demands using radio buttons instead of checkboxes. Here is a solution using radio buttons

```js
$('#getResult').on('click', getResult);

function getResult(){
  var result=[];
  $('input[name^=tc]:checked').each(function(){
      result.push($(this).val());
    });
  alert(result.toString());
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
1<br>
<input  name="tc0" value="Y" type="radio">Yes <br>
<input name="tc0"  value="N"type="radio">No<br>
2<br>
<input name="tc1" value="Y" type="radio">Yes <br>
<input name="tc1" value="N" type="radio">No<br>
3<br>
<input name="tc2" value="Y" type="radio">Yes <br>
<input name="tc2" value="N" type="radio">No<br>
<button id="getResult">Get Result</button>
```